# Pyspark: sbt assembly: maxpermisze as unrecognized VM option

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

```
lucas@ubuntu:~/spark/spark$ sbt/sbt assembly
NOTE: The sbt/sbt script has been relocated to build/sbt.
      Please update references to point to the new location.

      Invoking 'build/sbt assembly' now ...

Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512M'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

When trying to build spark I have the above error. I'm not sure how I can fix it. The Java version is 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I should say that java 1.9 is not officially out yet, therefore it's not recommended to use it unless you **really** have reasons for that. If using java 9 is not a must for you, then consider to switch to java 8. This will also fix the error because the MaxPermSize option in it is deprecated but not yet removed.
In case you still want to use java 9, you have to edit the file `project/SparkBuild.scala` to remove `-XX:MaxPermSize=...` from the `javaOptions` in it (I see 3 matches in spark 1.5.0)